# Right inheritance structure in messaging system in python (possible with bridge pattern)

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, bridge

I'm trying to develop some messaging system, which could use both ZeroMQ and RabbitMQ (possible even more like activeMQ).

So I thought like this:

Component in my messaging system could be either sender or receiver. Both of them have some address so I need generalization. So I've created it - AbstractMessagingNode with two more refined abstractions: AbstractReceiver and AbstractSender.

```
class AbstractMessagingNode():
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, host):
        self.host = host

class AbstractReceiver(AbstractMessagingNode):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    callback = None
    host = None
    def __init__(self, host, on_receive_callback):
        super(AbstractReceiver, self).__init__(host)
        self.callback = on_receive_callback

    def on_message_received(self, *args):
        self.callback(*args)

class AbstractSender(AbstractMessagingNode):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def send_message(self, message):
        pass
```

And at first I was working only with rabbitmq. So I've created two more refined abstraction for that (basically think about them as concrete implementations)

```
class BaseRabbitSender(AbstractSender):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    default_port_number = 5672

    def __init__(self, host):
        super(BaseRabbitSender, self).__init__(host)
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
            host=host))
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()

    @abstractmethod
    def send_message(self, message):
        pass

    def close_connection(self):
        self.connection.close()
```

etc...

All this was working well, until I've tried to stick zmq in that.

The problem is that zmqnode also could be either sender or receiver (in my case). But both receiver and sender need common methods and fields. I've tried to capture that with this class

```
class AbstractZmqNode(AbstractMessagingNode):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        super(AbstractZmqNode, self).__init__(host)
        self.port = port
        self.context = zmq.Context()

   def set_hwm(self, hwm):
        self.socket.set_hwm(hwm)

    @staticmethod
    def build_address(host, port):
        strings = [host, ':', str(port)]
        return ''.join(strings)
```

But that creates a problem with code duplication because in that case I need also AbstractZmqSender and AbstractZmqReceiver and that's no good.

I'm thinking about bridge pattern, but just don't know where to start, because in all examples of bridge pattern Abstraction is just an interface, but in my case it have some data fields.

I'm open to your help and suggestions.